# getopt not working correctly when run from unix command line

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line-arguments, getopt

I wrote (copied and pasted from Google and simplified) a C program to use getopt to print out the values of the arguments passed in from the Unix command line.

From Unix command line:

```
./myprog -a 0 -b 1 -c 2
```

My C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    while ((i = getopt(argc, argv, "abc")) != -1) {
        switch (i) {
            case 'a': 
               printf("A = %s\n", optarg);
               break;

            case 'b': 
               printf("B = %s\n", optarg);
               break;

            case 'c': 
               printf("C = %s\n", optarg);
               break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to program to print out each of the values passed e.g.

```
A = 0
B = 1
C = 2
```

However it is not printing out anything at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forget about ":" after any option with argument. If you will change one line

```
while ((i = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:c:")) != -1) {
```

you will get working variant.

Read properly `man 3 getopt`, it said about third argument of `getopt` that

… optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters.  If such a character is followed by  a  colon,  the  option  requires  an  argument,  so
       getopt()  places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg.  Two colons mean an option
       takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"),  then  it  is
       returned  in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero. …

Comment: Thanks @Eddy_Em. That has fixed it.

Just wondering about the use of merging characters together like what I originally had as I have seen that format on plenty of getopt examples e.g. "a:bc:d:ef". What does bc mean as opposed to b:c?

Comment: BTW in `man 3 getopt` there are two working examples of usage `getopt` and `getopt_long`.